# X is a Random Variable taking values {1,2,...} with P(X=k)=$c/[k(k+1)]$

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-functions

**Show $P(X\ge k)=c/k$**
I tried getting the integral for $X\ge k$. Didn't work out.
$$\int_k^{\infty} c/k(k+1)dk=-c*ln(|(1/\infty)+1|)+c*ln(|(1/k)+1|)$$
Which equals $c*ln(|(1/k)+1|)$, which I don't think can equal c/k

**Find c**
$$\int_1^\infty c/k(k+1)dk=1$$
So
$$-c*ln(|(1/\infty)+1|)+c*ln(|(1+1|)=1$$
Since $ln(|(1/+-\infty)+1|)=0$ I'm guessing c=1/ln(2)?

**Find the probability that X is odd**
For this I know that since this is a RV than spans from 1 to $\infty$ then probably half of the values will be odd. I'm guessing take the integral from 0 to infinity for c/(2k+1)(2k+2)?

Answer (score 1):

HINT

$X$ is an *integer-valued* random variable!  And $P(X=x)$ is an actual probability, not a probability density (pdf).  You cannot integrate $P()$ (you can only integrate pdf's).  Instead you need something *easier* - you can add them.

$$P(X \ge k) = P(X=k) + P(X=k+1) + P(X=k+2) + \dots = \sum_{j=k}^\infty P(X=j)$$

So you need to prove the above infinite summation equals $c/k$.

Finding $c$ is really easy: $P(X \ge 1) = 1$ by definition of $X$, and you already know what $P(X \ge k)$ is...

$P(X \,\,\text{odd})$ is yet another exercise in infinite summation.

Comment: How do I prove the infinite summation equals c/k? I'm not great at showing the limit of an infinite summation if you can point in that direction that'd help with the first and third question

Comment: Don't I have to get integrals to calculate the infinite sums?

Comment: ${c \over k(k+1)}$ is a very special form: it equals ${c \over k} - {c \over k+1}$ (verify this yourself).  This very special form makes part 1 easy.  However, I actually don't know how to solve part 3.  To be more precise, I know the answer because I just looked it up, but I don't know how to prove that answer.  (I do not know if integrating will help or not.)

Comment: how does $c/k(k+1)=c/k-c/k+1$. I'm wondering because I have seen that before but I don't really know how they got there.

Comment: uh.... that's just partial fraction expansion.  high school (middle school?) algebra. 
 nothing mysterious.  don't overthink that bit. :)  i.e. take $c/k  - c/(k+1)$, find the common denominator, etc.

Comment: Is there one for $1/(2m+1)(2m+2)$? Cause if so then we can solve the P(X is odd) one.

Comment: Well that's just the same but substitute with $c=1, k=2m+1$.  Hey, sorry, I gotta sleep now (1:45am).  Good luck esp. with part 3!